# Parsing JSON data from an API to Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to get data from an api ( https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=ETH&limit=30&aggregate=1&e=CCCAGG ) to pandas. 
API gives data in Json.

```
df = pd.read_json('new.json' , orient = 'columns')
```

Error: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.

Data i need:-
Image Link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsCA5.jpg

I am really new to this, any help would be fantastic.

Comment: Are you downloading correctly yours data? What is 'new.json'?

Comment: How are you downloading the JSON?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you're passing the entirety of your JSON to the `read_json` function, when you should only be passing the data stored in the `Data` attribute.

---

If you're downloading your data programmatically, I would recommend `requests`:

```
In [422]: import requests

In [416]: data = requests.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=ETH&limit=30&aggregate=1&e=CCCAGG')\
                         .json()['Data']
```

`data` is now a dictionary, not a JSON string. You can call the `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` function to parse the data, like this:

```
In [420]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

In [421]: df.head()
Out[421]: 
   close   high    low   open        time  volumefrom   volumeto
0  12.29  11.55  12.73  12.54  1500595200    72064.93  875383.96
1  12.22  11.93  12.61  12.29  1500681600    39624.40  489345.17
2  12.03  11.94  12.37  12.22  1500768000    37270.80  452462.43
3  12.22  11.99  12.36  12.03  1500854400    28582.22  347606.39
4  12.59  12.22  13.03  12.22  1500940800    54004.34  676716.41
```

---

If you insist on using `pd.from_json`, then you must only pass the string data that is contained inside the `Data` attribute of the JSON response, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Thanks alot, it works. Just wanted to know how can i delete Column 1 (0,1,2,3,4..) and sort it out with time?

Also, is there any way to edit Json to get just the data in Data column, so that i can use 'pd.from_json'